# SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke is making a POST request and I want it to make GET, how do I do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap-client

This is part of the code in the class I use to call the web service (this class inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol). Whenever I call localidades() I get error 405 from the server, this is because localidades() is sending a post instead of a get, and the server is configured to allow get only. How can I change request type?

I tried to change request type by overrideing the GetWebRequest() method (apart from adding basic authentication), but it is only adding the basic authentication and not changing the request type.

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password"));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        return request;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/localidades", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public string localidades() {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("localidades", new object[0]);
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is always an HTTP POST. If the server expects a GET, it isn't hosting the SOAP service correctly.

Comment: Ok thx for the answer, this program was previously working with a local web service and they told me to modify it to work with a remote web service. I will use HttpClient instead.